# Can the blackscreen in background during scale animation applied to activity be colored

Tags: android, android-animation, android-lifecycle

I'hv applied scale animation to my activity on activity open. So can the black background be given a color. 
As the previous activity goes in pause so is something possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background to the window of the activity like

```
getWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffff0000));
```